# Best way to extract data from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
__cfduid=d2eec71493b48565be764ad44a52a7b191399561601015; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.planetminecraft.com; HttpOnly
```

I want to use regex and get something like this:

```
[0] = __cfduid=d2eec71493b48565be764ad44a52a7b191399561601015
[1] = expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT
[2] = path=/
[3] = domain=.planetminecraft.com
[4] = HttpOnly
```

I tried this regex:

```
[\A|;](.*?)[\Z|;]
```

I don't understand why `\A`. works but `[\A]` not, how can I create (`\A` or `;`)?

In final form of this regex I want to get from string this:

```
[0] = {
    [0] = __cfduid
    [1] = d2eec71493b48565be764ad44a52a7b191399561601015
}
[1] = {
    [0] = expires
    [1] = Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT
}
[2] = {
    [0] = path
    [1] = /
}
[3] = {
    [0] = domain
    [1] = .planetminecraft.com
}
[4] = {
    [0] = HttpOnly
}
```

Comment: Is using `split()` an option? Or, rather, what flavor of regex is this?

Comment: What language, javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try matching on this regex:

```
\s*([^=;]+)(?:=([^=;]+))?
```

Description:

```
\s*         # Match any spaces
([^=;]+)    # Match any non = or ; characters
(?:
  =         # Match an = sign
  ([^=;]+)  # Match any non = or ; characters.
)?          # Make this group optional
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wF1oB3)

In code:

```
string text = "__cfduid=d2eec71493b48565be764ad44a52a7b191399561601015; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.planetminecraft.com; HttpOnly";

var regex = new Regex(@"\s*([^=;]+)(?:=([^=;]+))?");
var matches = regex.Matches(text);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value + "\n" + match.Groups[2].Value + "\n");
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/RWxR1o)

---

`\A` works but `[\A]` does not because when you put `\A` in a character class, it loses its meaning like most regex metacharacters. For instance, `+` and `*` also lose their meaning. In `[\A]`, the regex is actually trying to match `\A` and since it doesn't have a particular meaning in a character class, it means a literal `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets create a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html); you need parentheses for grouping, preferably non-[capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). And you need to use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of the second group since each semicolon can only match once:

```
(?:\A|;)(.*?)(?=\Z|;)
```

That still doesn't get you your parameter/value pairs, so you might want to be more specific:

```
(?:\A|;\s*)([^=]*)(?:=([^;]*))?(?=\Z|;)
```

(`[^=]*` matches any number of characters except `=`.)

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/vH2wX3).